# Plotting the deformed shape of a rectangle

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot a rectangle using graphics  :

```
rc = Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}];
```

and add a deformation function to it:

$$\chi(\mathbf X)=X_1(1+X_2)\hat{\mathbf e}_1+X_2(1+3X_1)\hat{\mathbf e}_2$$

This deformation function specifies new coordinates as functions of old ones. How can I plot the new shape?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/GeometricTransforms.html) in the documentation?

Comment: @m_goldberg, seeing as the deformation is of the three-dimensional sort, `Graphics[]` won't help the OP. `Graphics3D[]` might...maybe even `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @J. M. The reference I gave gives information on and further links to both 2D and 3D transforms.

Comment: @m_goldberg, true, but if my memory of the available `TransformationFunction[]`s serves me right, they won't be able to do the transformation requested...

Comment: @J. M. this deformation function does not change the third coordinate. So I want to neglect the third coordinate and work with two dimensions.

Comment: In that case, ponder upon the result of `{ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}], ParametricPlot[{u (1 + v), v (1 + 3 u)}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]} // GraphicsRow`.

Comment: @m_goldberg , I have seen this link, but it seems that it only contains linear transformations like rotation, I do not know how to use an arbitrary non linear transformation.

Comment: @J. M. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you understood how `ParametricPlot[]` worked in that snippet I posted, may I suggest writing an answer to your own question, so that we can gauge your understanding of that solution?

Comment: @J. M. Good idea, I'll do it.

Answer (score 9):

As J. M. suggested in comments, `ParametricPlot[]` can be used to show this deformation:

```
{ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}], 
  ParametricPlot[{u (1 + v), v (1 + 3 u)}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0,1}]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

Comment: Looks right, but the setting `AspectRatio -> 1` will of course necessarily distort your region further. Someone looking at the pictures should then be careful to note that the scales on the axes in the picture on the left and the picture on the right are different.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of approaching this is to map the image of the rectangle rather than the geometric object itself.

```
img = Image[Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}]]
```

This turns the graphic into an image which can then be mapped using the specified function:

```
ImageForwardTransformation[img, {#[[1]] (1 + #[[2]])/4, #[[2]] (1 + 3 #[[1]])/4} &]
```

[image]

The only wrinkle here is that the range of the image needs to be in {0,1} so I scaled both entries by the largest value (4) so that would show the whole image of the distorted rectangle.

Of course, this method maps not only the rectangle itself, but also the contents of the rectangle (if any). So for example, the same mapping can be applied to an image.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zVEI.png"];
```

[image]

```
ImageForwardTransformation[img, {#[[1]] (#[[2]] + 1)/4, 
                  (1 + 3 #[[1]]) #[[2]]/4} &, Background -> White]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `ImageForwardTransformation[Image[Graphics[{Blue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]}, ImagePadding -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None]], # ({#[[2]], 3 #[[1]]} + 1) &, Background -> 1., DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 4}}]`.